# Is there any difference setting width: auto; and width: fit-content;?

Tags: html, css

From what I know, setting width: fit-content; to the element simply means that the element width will take up the available space but never less than the min-content within the element. But, isn't the default width: auto; behaves the same as well?

Just wondering when should I use width: fit-content;?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The question is perfectly valid (and the answer is great). There is just a problem with the grammar in the question, which can not be fixed, as the "Suggested edit queue is full".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`width: auto` is the default width for all elements, so the width will rely on display types (block, inline, etc.) to show respectively.

To make you understand better about `width:auto`, I put 2 code snippets below

Case 1: Using `div` with `display: block` as default

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20em;
}

.item {
  width: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item with more text in it.</div>
  <div class="item">Item with more text in it, hopefully it's lengthy enough for the demo</div>
</div>
```

Case 2: Using `span` with `display: inline` as default

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20em;
}

.item {
  width: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="item">Item</span>
  <span class="item">Item with more text in it.</span>
  <span class="item">Item with more text in it, hopefully it's lengthy enough for the demo</span>
</div>
```

So basically, `display: block` will take up the whole width for element display, and `display: inline` and `display: inline-block` will align with content width. The next question is why we don't use `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` instead of `width: fit-content`?

Let's check the below code snippet for `div` with `width: fit-content`

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20em;
}

.item {
  width: fit-content;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Item</div>
  <div class="item">Item with more text in it.</div>
  <div class="item">Item with more text in it, hopefully it's lengthy enough for the demo</div>
</div>
```

You can see that each content line has been shown with an individual color box, and it does not consume other lines' space

As your question

> Just wondering when should I use width: fit-content;?

In my personal experience, I've been usually using `width: fit-content;` when I want to show tags with fit borders

[image]

[Source](https://dribbble.com/tags/warning_message)

All my tags can be shown in different lines but borders will be displayed respectively by content, so `width: fit-content` is a good choice for me.

P/s: Actually, we can achieve this design in other ways like using a wrapper, using flexbox, etc. But I personally like `width: fit-content` because it's simpler. One thing I'd like to note is that this approach does not work well with Internet Explorer (check browser compatibility [here](https://caniuse.com/?search=fit-content))

Comment: probably the more important answer would be concerning the difference between 'width:auto' and 'width: fit-content' when the container is always a flex one

Answer (score -1):

*from chatgpt*

In CSS, the `auto` and `fit-content` values are often used with properties like `width` and `height` to define the size of elements.

- **Auto:** When `auto` is used, the browser calculates the size of the element based on its content and any other constraints applied. For example, if you have a block-level element with `width: auto;`, it will expand to fill its container horizontally.
- **Fit-content:** On the other hand, `fit-content` sets the size of the element to fit its content, but with a maximum constraint. It's like `auto`, but it won't expand beyond a specified size. For instance, `width: fit-content(200px);` will make the element as wide as its content, up to a maximum of 200 pixels.

So, while both are used to size elements based on their content, `fit-content` adds a limit to how much the element can expand.